# java.lang.VerifyError: me.xxx.menu.MenuListFragment only on Android 2.x.x

Tags: actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu, verifyerror

after almost 2 week trying to solve this strange problem, I give up!
Basically a get the java.lang.VerifyError every time I try to run my app
only in devices with Android 2.x.x. From 3.x.x all are going well.

In the project I'm using this two external library:

1. Action Bar Sherlock - http://actionbarsherlock.com/ - updated at the v4.4.0
2. Sliding Menu - https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

This is what the LogCat return every time:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.VerifyError: me.xxx.menu.MenuListFragment
at me.xxx.menu.BaseSlidingMenuActivity.onCreate(BaseSlidingMenuActivity.java:46)
at me.xxx.menu.SlidingMenuCustomAnimation.onCreate(SlidingMenuCustomAnimation.java:28)
at me.xxx.XXXActivity.onCreate(XXXActivity.java:130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is how the BaseSlidingMenuActivity.java looks like around the line 46:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setTitle(mTitleRes);

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.frame_content);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    mFrag = new MenuListFragment();  <--- ERROR HERE!

    t.replace(R.id.frame_content, mFrag);
    t.commit();

    } else {

    mFrag =(SherlockListFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frame_content);
}

    ...
    ...
}
```

Where MenuListFragment() is a SlidingFragmentActivity that extend a SherlockFragmentActivity
and implements SlidingActivityBase.

Of course I googled the problem, and seems that a lot of people are getting this
issue with the last version of the Android SDK tool, i.e. v22.x.x , in fact a have 
the v22.6.3.

Some people resolved the VerifyError just putting the Check on the "Private Libraries"
box, inside "BuildPath->Configure BuildPath->Order and Export" menù, as explained 
in other conversation about the VerifyError, but for me doesn't work, even because the "Private Libraries" was already checked. So the libraries/imports situation seems to be ok!

Hoping that someone already fund a solution for that! I'm getting crazy! :D

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution!

Recap! Basically the are two main reason in which you can get this error:

1. (In my case) I was getting the VerifyError all the time that I tried to run my app on devices with API Level under 10 , because I was trying to catch an SQLiteDatabaseLockedException that are supported from the Android API Level 11. So to solve it check that every Exception or possible method (i.e. String.isEmpty() is supported from API Level 9) is supported form your minimum API Level.
2. While I was searching for a solution I found a lot of people that got the VerifyError because there was some problem with Libraries Imports, as explained in this post: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/23/do-not-manually-modify-eclipse-build-path-except-now-r22.html

Hope that will help someone beyond me! :D

Bye Bye! Caterpillar.